# SOLVED: App with TabLayout with FragmentPagerAdapter and ViewPager crashes

Tags: java, android

Solution: updated dependecies

I want to make an app with three tabs, setup with a ViewPager and TabLayout. I'm using FragmentPagerAdapter. Layouts and activities are error-free, but still the app crashes. Activities, layouts and crashreport below.

```java
2019-08-11 14:03:15.791 25598-25598/ga.rndevelopment.inventory E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ga.rndevelopment.inventory, PID: 25598
    java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #42 bootstrap method
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(TabLayout.java:2592)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.update(TabLayout.java:2508)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.setTab(TabLayout.java:2437)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:1501)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.newTab(TabLayout.java:855)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.populateFromPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:1477)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.setPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:1468)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:1379)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:1340)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:1320)
        at ga.rndevelopment.inventory.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7458)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7448)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3382)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3587)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2185)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7593)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Bootstrap method returned null
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(TabLayout.java:2592) 
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.update(TabLayout.java:2508) 
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.setTab(TabLayout.java:2437) 
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:1501) 
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.newTab(TabLayout.java:855) 
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.populateFromPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:1477) 
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.setPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:1468) 
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:1379) 
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:1340) 
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:1320) 
        at ga.rndevelopment.inventory.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7458) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7448) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1286) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3382) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3587) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2185) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7593) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987) 
2019-08-11 14:03:15.810 25598-25598/ga.rndevelopment.inventory I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25598 SIG: 9
```

**MainActivity**

```java
package ga.rndevelopment.inventory;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new TabOne(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TabTwo(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFragment(new TabThree(), "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**activity_main**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            android:layout_gravity="top" />


    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**PagerAdapter**

```java
package ga.rndevelopment.inventory;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> FragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> FragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return FragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return FragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        FragmentList.add(fragment);
        FragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return FragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

**TabOne**

```java
package ga.rndevelopment.inventory;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class TabOne extends Fragment {
    public TabOne() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_standard, container, false);
    }
}
```

As Android Studio doesn't throw an error anywhere, I don't know in which class I need to search for eventual missing parts of code. Anyone some reproduction ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the problem is here:
`at ga.rndevelopment.inventory.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21) ` so it's about invoking `tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);`

Comment: Kindly check your dependencies in build.gradle

Comment: @JawadAhmed I've updated my Material dependecie from alpha8 to alpha9 and now it works, strangely enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Bootstrap method returned
>   null

work on this one...casting goes wrong with null values.